# Laravel validation rules - regex

Tags: laravel-5

I need to use Laravel Validation with **regex** that allow string as *1,2,3,7*

Some as this:

```
$arr_rules = [ 'order'  => 'min:3|regex:[0-9+,]',
               ...
             ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr_rules = [ 'order'  => 'min:3|regex:^([0-9]+\,+)*[0-9]+$',
           ...
];
```

Comment: ok, this regex work if you add ^ to the end. Error in Laravel show it.

Comment: well that strange, because `^` sign means begining of the line

Comment: You are missing regex delimiters !

Comment: You do not need them in rule definition. Laravel add them